# Is there any way to return three containers in one getter?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, getter

I'm wondering is there any way to get access to three containers at once.
I have class like :

```
class DataContainer
{

private:
    std::vector<Rental*> rentals;
    std::vector<Vehicle*> vehicles;
    std::vector<Client*> clients;

public:
    DataContainer();
    bool loadObjects();
    bool createRentals();
    std::string showVehicles() const;
    std::string showClients() const;
    std::string showDetails() const ;
    std::tuple< std::vector<Vehicle*>type1, std::vector<Client*>type2, std::vector<Rental*>type3 > getContainers();
    virtual ~DataContainer();

};
```

I would like to have possibility to access from other class to these containers, that's why I would like to set some getter, but here comes my problem. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but the errors I get are :

```
include\DataContainer.h|74|error: template argument 1 is invalid|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

my function looks like this :

```
std::tuple< std::vector<Vehicle*>type1, std::vector<Client*>type2, std::vector<Rental*>type3 > DataContainer::getContainers()
{
   return std::make_tuple(vehicles,clients,rentals);
}
```

Hope someone will be able to give me some hint, if that makes any difference I'm working on C++11.

Comment: `std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>` expects `T1, T2, T3` to be types. `std::vector<Vehicle*>type1` is not a valid type. `std::vector<Vehicle*>` is.

Comment: `type2` etc. should not be in the `std::tuple< std::vector<Vehicle*>type1, std::vector<Client*>type2, std::vector<Rental*>type3 > getContainers();` lines. However, this looks like fairly broken class design to begin with.

Comment: Even if the error is fixed, you may end up copying **a lot** of pointers just to return the three vectors. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

The type should be

```
std::tuple< std::vector<Vehicle*>, std::vector<Client*>, std::vector<Rental*>>
```

The field names are invalid.

As an alternative to the tuple you can define a struct type which contains the 3 containers and return that.